# micro-usb headset on android 2.3

Tags: usb, audio, headphones, headset

I have a samsung galaxy ace which I am trying to setup to work with a usb headset. The problem is that the usb headset has a micro-usb connector and my phone does not seem to be recognizing it at all.

I only need to use the headset to activate a phone call. I do not need to hear any audio from it, I just need to be able to press the 'phone' button on the headset and have it answer the phone.

I've read up on the android developers guide and it seems as though a passive usb headset must be communicated with in host mode. It also says host mode is only available on android 3.1+

I was wondering if anyone could tell me if there is any way to get this to work? using the specific speaker output port is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is impossible.

The headset requires power from the device. Android versions before 3.1 state that they can not support powering the usb bus.

From the developer guide:

> When the Android-powered device is in host mode, it acts as the USB host and powers the bus. When the Android-powered device is in USB accessory mode, the connected USB hardware (an Android USB accessory in this case) acts as the host and powers the bus.
>
> USB accessory and host modes are directly supported in Android 3.1 (API level 12) or newer platforms. USB accessory mode is also backported to Android 2.3.4 (API level 10) as an add-on library to support a broader range of devices. Device manufacturers can choose whether or not to include the add-on library on the device's system image.

unless there is a custom android OS that supports usb host mode, I believe what I'm trying to achieve is impossible